# calling the rest api post from mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, pipedrive-api

I want to post the RESTful service from  the name of the url is 
"https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/persons?api_token=tS5adsXC6V2nH991"
list of complete API is present in "https://developers.pipedrive.com/v1"

Following is my code

```
  string URL = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/persons?api_token=tS5adsXC6V2nH991";
            string DATA = @"{""object"":{""name"":""rohit sukhla""}}";
       var dataToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DATA);
                //Passyour service url to the create method
                var req =
                HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
                req.ContentType = "application/json";
                req.ContentLength = dataToSend.Length;
                req.Method = "POST";
               req.GetRequestStream().Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
                var response1 = req.GetResponse();
```

I am getting the error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

please help

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the `GetBytes("")` part? You're sending an empty request. Additionally there are easier ways to send HTTP requests than plain `WebRequest`. *Also* are you sure you wanted to publicly post that API key? If it was a secret you should invalidate and change it on the server end immediately.

Comment: This is not my actual api key this is dummy one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my usual strategy for posting to external APIs, I hope it helps

```
using (var http = new HttpClient()) {
    // Define authorization headers here, if any
    // http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue);

    var data = new ModelType {
        name = nameValue,
        email = emailValue
    };

    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    var request = http.PostAsync("[api url here]", content);

    var response = request.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModelType>(response);
}
```

The `request` can also be awaited, instead of calling `.Result` directly.

To use this approach you need to create a c# model based on the response json structure. Oftentimes I use http://json2csharp.com/, provide a typical json response from the endpoint I'm interested in, and the c# model gets generated for me automatically.

Comment: Hi,Thanks this really worked for me. now only looking for the data that i received on the sucess?

Comment: I'm glad to hear. I've updated my answer with a response handling strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper object with a key called "object" looks extraneous to me. You should probably post just the inner object.

Comment: check still same error   " string DATA1 = @"{{""name"":""rohit sukhla""}}";"

Comment: That's not even valid JSON anymore. It has an extra pair of `{}` around it.